# How do I set `svn:global-ignores` in Subversion 1.8?

Tags: svn

There's a new `svn:global-ignores` thing in Subversion 1.8 but even after reading the very wordy documentation from the retro site:

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.props.special.ignore.html

I still am none the wiser about what this string `svn:global-ignores` actually *is* and how I set it?

My goal is to set an ignore pattern for the whole team, like how in Git there's an ignore file for the repo that's in the repo.

Thank you!

P.S. Do I need a particular server version or is this a client thing?

Comment: I sort of get the reason for the down-vote, but I think this would make for a good Q/A. I expect to have to answer my own question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use a "versioned property" set on the root directory of the repository called `svn:global-ignores`. This is new in v1.8 and applies recursively.

There is also `svn:ignore` which applies to the directory its set on only. It can be set recursively, but doesn't work the same way as the above, so new directories won't 'receive' the setting.

```
svn propset svn:global-ignores {newline delimited ignore patterns}
```

Now I couldn't work out how to set newline-delimited data in a Windows Command Prompt so I just used the Properties editor in TortoiseSVN.

I remove my local Tortoise ignore list and tested with a Thumbs.db file and the setting seems to work down the tree. The property is written to the repo and must be committed like a code change. Done.

Answer (score -2):

From the SVN book:

> Unlike svn:ignore however, the svn:global-ignores property is
>   inheritable and applies to all paths under the directory on which
>   the property is set, not just the immediate children of the directory

[Of course only a 1.8 or newer Subversion client will recognize the inheritability and special meaning of the svn:global-ignores property!](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.props.special.ignore.html#ftn.idp9803456)

> how I set it?

`svn help ps` will output help for using the "ps" command (short for "propset").

Comment: Thanks. It's a "property", but where and and what? I'm trying to set the ignore pattern once for everyone, I get no info from this page as to whether this property is stored on the server or locally, and the doc doesn't tell you how to set it. I'm a Git person coming to SVN. `svn help ps` assume I know `ps` is `propset` which I didn't.

Comment: Someone that knows SVN won't see how this documentation is lacking since they'll auto-fill the gaps.

Comment: @Lazy Badger, this answer is too emotional, IMO. Don't aggro :3

Comment: @LazyBadger I use SO to ask many small questions because if we all QA'd then SO would accumulate even more quality answers. I "QA myself" all the time on here for other people's benefit and my own in future, even when I can immediately answer the question. That's not lazy. I don't care about being attacked for it, down-voted or whatever, because I know it'll help someone out there.